# What do the two symbols => in a row mean

Tags: typescript, lambda, symbols

I know lambdas and function like type, but what is this:

displayFunc: (string) => string = x => x;

Two symbols "=>" confuse me.  What is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is type the other one is implementation.

```
type MyFunctionType = (string) => string

const displayFunc: MyFunctionType = x => x;

/// OR

const displayFunc: MyFunctionType = function(x: string): string {
  return x;
};
```

`(string) => string` means a function type that takes `string` and returns `string`;

`x => x` is an identity function, meaning it returns the same thing it was passed in.